# Cannot find module when import class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I import the class "User" in the index.ts and want to output a user. When compiling, I get the error message "Cannot find module". However, as soon as I consider the extension .js when importing, it works.

In all the tutorials I've watched now, I don't see anywhere that the extension is taken into consider when importing.

***User.ts***

```
export class User {
    static getUser() {
        return {
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "password": "123456"
        }
    }
}
```

***index.ts***

```
import {User} from "./User";

const user = User.getUser()
console.log(user)
```

***package.json***

```
...
"type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
...
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Comment: If it node.js then you need to add file extension. `import {User} from "./User.js";`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there no way to automate this process? For example, when compiling?